# Why am I getting these exceptions when trying to load a .csv file into Weka 3.8.6?

Tags: java, csv, java-8, weka

I have a large (~1gb) csv file I am trying to load into Weka 3.8.6. It used to let me try to load CSV files, but I was getting an issue with memory. After updating heap size and trying to load again, Weka won't even attempt to load the CSV and instead throws a couple of different exceptions at me. Here is the complete console output of loading Weka and trying to open the CSV file in ArffViewer:

```
Environment variable 'JAVA_OPTS' does not exist!
Environment variable 'CLASSPATH' does not exist!
WARNING: A terminally deprecated method in java.lang.System has been called
WARNING: System::setSecurityManager has been called by weka.gui.GUIChooserApp (file:/C:/Program%20Files/Weka-3-8-6/weka.jar)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of weka.gui.GUIChooserApp
WARNING: System::setSecurityManager will be removed in a future release
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: class javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicFileChooserUI$AcceptAllFileFilter cannot be cast to class weka.gui.ExtensionFileFilterWithClass (javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicFileChooserUI$AcceptAllFileFilter is in module java.desktop of loader 'bootstrap'; weka.gui.ExtensionFileFilterWithClass is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
        weka.gui.ConverterFileChooser.configureCurrentConverter(ConverterFileChooser.java:743)
        weka.gui.ConverterFileChooser.showOpenDialog(ConverterFileChooser.java:553)
        weka.gui.arffviewer.ArffViewerMainPanel.loadFile(ArffViewerMainPanel.java:659)
        weka.gui.arffviewer.ArffViewerMainPanel.actionPerformed(ArffViewerMainPanel.java:1069)
        java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
        java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(Unknown Source)
        java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
        java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

        at weka.gui.ConverterFileChooser.configureCurrentConverter(ConverterFileChooser.java:743)
        at weka.gui.ConverterFileChooser.showOpenDialog(ConverterFileChooser.java:553)
        at weka.gui.arffviewer.ArffViewerMainPanel.loadFile(ArffViewerMainPanel.java:659)
        at weka.gui.arffviewer.ArffViewerMainPanel.actionPerformed(ArffViewerMainPanel.java:1069)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: class javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicFileChooserUI$AcceptAllFileFilter cannot be cast to class weka.gui.ExtensionFileFilterWithClass (javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicFileChooserUI$AcceptAllFileFilter is in module java.desktop of loader 'bootstrap'; weka.gui.ExtensionFileFilterWithClass is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
        weka.gui.ConverterFileChooser.configureCurrentConverter(ConverterFileChooser.java:743)
        weka.gui.ConverterFileChooser.showOpenDialog(ConverterFileChooser.java:553)
        weka.gui.explorer.PreprocessPanel.setInstancesFromFileQ(PreprocessPanel.java:1004)
        weka.gui.explorer.PreprocessPanel$5.actionPerformed(PreprocessPanel.java:341)
        java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
        java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(Unknown Source)
        java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
        java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

        at weka.gui.ConverterFileChooser.configureCurrentConverter(ConverterFileChooser.java:743)
        at weka.gui.ConverterFileChooser.showOpenDialog(ConverterFileChooser.java:553)
        at weka.gui.explorer.PreprocessPanel.setInstancesFromFileQ(PreprocessPanel.java:1004)
        at weka.gui.explorer.PreprocessPanel$5.actionPerformed(PreprocessPanel.java:341)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I modified the .ini file to this to update heap size here:

```
# The JAVA_OPTS environment variable (if set). Can be used as an alternative way to set
# the heap size (or any other JVM option)
javaOpts=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xmx8000m
```

I have tried to uninstall and reinstall but it doesn't seem to make a difference. However, it also doesn't seem to do a clean uninstall as when i reinstalled the program, this .ini file stayed the same.

Comment: This is software written with some tricks in use that no longer work in the java version you are using, or at least are slated to no longer work in the (near) future. Use java8 to run this stuff.

Comment: This does seem to be the case, after a bit more digging into the documentation I realized that the program uses a Java Virtual Machine which used an incompatible version of Java. Thank you!